# statically link dynamic loaded binaries into binary

Tags: linux, hyperlink, cross-platform

I have a compiled binary `file.bin`, which is dynamically linked to others.

```
$ ldd file.bin
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffc017c6000)
    so.6 => /usr/lib/libm.so.6 (0x00007f3af51d7000)
    so.2 => /usr/lib/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f3af51d1000)
    so.6 => /usr/lib/libc.so.6 (0x00007f3af5008000)
    ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 => /usr/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f3af61a7000)
```

I need to be lib-independent, because my target system uses different version of those libraries. (executing `file.bin` on the target yields errors: `/lib64/libm.so.6: version 'GLIBC_2.27' not found`). I do not have the source code of `file.bin`.
My attempt is to add those dynamically linked files into that binary, I could not find any tools to do that. Is it even possible?

If that's helping: I can run the `file.bin` on a kernel `5.10.6-arch1-1` and the target is a kernel `3.10.0-1062.9.1.el7.x86_64`

Comment: Without the source code for `file.bin`, you cannot build a static binary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without the source code for `file.bin`, you cannot build a static binary.

However, there are a number of tools such as [Statifier](https://statifier.sourceforge.net/) and [Ermine](https://magicermine.com/) which can help you package the existing dynamic binary and its dependencies into a single binary.

Quoting from the Ermine website:

> What can Ermine do for you?
>
> Ermine packs a GNU/Linux application together with any needed shared libraries and data files into a single executable. This file can be copied to any GNU/Linux host and run without further modifications.
>
> Basic functionality:
>
> - Only one file is installed
> - Escape from “dependency hell”
> - Independence from package management (RPM, DEB, TGZ, ...)
> - No version mismatch between the executable and its auxiliary files
> - No host-dependent side-effects: the application and the target host's software environment do not interfere with each other